# Combining two parallel observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm stuck with switching observables. Here's a condition: first observable should always emit and will be handled as main value stream, second observable should produce `void` value and then it will be handled as a side-effect.
I'm very confused in different combining operators. Now I'm staying on concatMap but it also works incorrectly.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const { Observable } = Rx;
  const one = document.getElementById('one');
  const two = document.getElementById('two');
  const one$ = Observable
        .fromEvent(one, 'click')
        .map(() => [1,2,3,4]);
  const two$ = Observable
        .fromEvent(two, 'click')
        .map(() => void 0);

  const sideEffect = values => console.log('Doing something with data', values);

  one$
        .concatMap(initialValues => two$
          .do(() => sideEffect(initialValues))
          .map(() => initialValues))
        .subscribe(x => alert(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2)))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
<button id="one">One</button>
<button id="two">Two</button>
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you might want to have 2 separate subscriptions in this case one for each observable. Otherwise you will have to add logic to defer between the values being returned from each observable.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve a bit more.  It looks like you want the second observable to modify the data from the first.  How?  In your example you seem to add a `b` property when the second observable occurs.  Should it modify values that come after it?  Or should it also modify values that came before?

Comment: @BenjiLees the case with two subscriptions not suitable for me. After `two$` emits I need to make side-effect based on the last value from `one$`

Comment: @Pace I have very simplified the issue because the real Observable chain is big enough.
In real world it handles multiple DOM events and `Subject`s. When the second observable occurs I add property `b` for example of side-effect. I think I need to change this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$two` needs to modify the last value from `$one` and then emit that modified value you could create a behavior subject.

```
  const values$ = new BehaviorSubject();
  const one$ = Observable
        .fromEvent(one, 'click')
        .map(() => [1,2,3,4]);
  const two$ = Observable
        .fromEvent(two, 'click')
        .map(() => void 0);

  const sideEffect = values => console.log('Doing something with data', values);

  one$.subscribe(values => {
    values$.next(values);
  });
  two$.subscribe(() => {
    let currentValue = values$.value;
    let modifiedValue = sideEffect(currentValue);
    values$.next(modifiedValue);
  });

  values$.subscribe(x => alert(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer